# iOS weird error: dyld: Symbol not found: __dealloc?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I suddenly getting the below error, which is not allowing any application to run in simulator. The app just crashes.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __dealloc
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

Please suggest !

Comment: I think some framework is deleted. Check your trash if it is not there then you have to reinstall xcode.

Comment: @Indrajeet  Deleted XCode ad reinstalled, but that doesnt helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of struggling came to know that, my OS files got corrupted. So, I have formatted my machine and reinstalled with fresh MAC OS X Mavericks.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: My project is working fine in xcode5.1.1 and ios 7.1.1 but whenever I run the project in xcoode6 it showing the error, can you please help  me on this.

Comment: For many this would not be an appropriate solution. Does anyone else has got this working in some other way?

Comment: How did you even find out your OS files were corrupted?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html), the issue is that you are linking against new frameworks that were added to both Yosemite and iOS 8 while running in iOS 7.1.  Unfortunately, this causes dyld to try bringing in the host version of the library when running in the iOS 7.1 simulator runtime.

> If an app is weak linked against frameworks new in iOS 8 SDK and OS X
>   10.10 SDK, it may fail to run if the run destination is an iOS Simulator for older iOS runtimes and the host system is running OS X
>   Yosemite. (17807439)

Additionally, this can occur if your iOS 7.1 simulator runtime is not fully installed (eg: due to an interrupted installation).  If this occurs, dyld will similarly fall back to the host for the missing libraries if available.

iOS 8.0 and later have their own dyld that will reject pulling in host versions of libraries and thus will prevent this class of problems in the future.

The iOS 7.1 Simulator runtime that is installed by Xcode 6.2 and later was updated to address this issue.

Comment: Can confirm that it happened on a not fully installed SDK

Answer (score -1):

Try locating a typo in an `import` statement, perhaps `inport` was typed accidentally instead?

Comment: No, that was not a problem. Even a fresh new single view based application not working.

Answer (score -1):

This is official bug in Apple tools. I came across to the same issue these days. Updating to the latest version will be okay.

mac-ruilong:~ winroot$ xcodebuild -showsdks

OS X SDKs:

```
OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
OS X 10.10                      -sdk macosx10.10
```

iOS SDKs:

```
iOS 8.1                         -sdk iphoneos8.1
```

iOS Simulator SDKs:

```
Simulator - iOS 8.1             -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
```

Reference:
[Xcode 5.1 iOS simulator 7.1 black screen issue ( dyld: Symbol not found: __dealloc )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742058/xcode-5-1-ios-simulator-7-1-black-screen-issue-dyld-symbol-not-found-deall/26763754#26763754)