# XCode 4.6 - Failed to launch application due to build error?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

When I tried to launch an application, getting the build error as below. Could not able to launch any application. Using XCode 4.6.

```
    dyld: Symbol not found: _audit_token_to_egid  Referenced from: 
/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfigurati  Expected in: 
/Users/easwar/Softwares/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Develo
per/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/libbsm.0.dyl in 
/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguratio2014-06-
08 20:26:20.127 ibtoold[2696:507] Init failed: Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)"2014-06-08 
20:26:20.128 ibtoold[2696:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in 
/SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-
2083/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:309Details:  IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool() failed: 
Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error 
communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x4011b2080 {NSUnderlyingError=0x400a26de0 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", 
NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS 
Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for 
"Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., 
NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (2697) failed to launch and 
exited with status (null), signal 5.}Function: id<IBCocoaTouchTool> 
IBAttachToCocoaTouchToolFailingGracefully(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *, NSError **)Thread:   
<NSThread: 0x400409be0>{name = (null), num = 1}Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com 
with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.2014-06-08 20:26:20.182 
ibtoold[2696:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in 
/SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-
\2083/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:39Details:  Failed to launch cocoa touch tool: 
Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Interface Builder encountered an error 
communicating with the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x4011b2080 {NSUnderlyingError=0x400a26de0 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)", 
NSLocalizedDescription=Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS 
Simulator., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for 
"Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., 
NSLocalizedFailureReason="Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (2697) failed to launch and 
exited with status (null), signal 5.}Object:   <NSThread: 0x400409be0>Method:   -
cocoaTouchToolForTargetRuntime:Thread:   <NSThread: 0x400409be0>{name = (null), num = 1}Hints: 
NoneBacktrace:  0  0x0000000100c6d6b3 -[DVTAssertionHandler 
handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundatio  1  
0x0000000100c6d4e4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundatio  2  0x00000001051510c6 (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  3  0x00000001051c49fa (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  4  0x00000001051c499f (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  5  0x00007fff85c0028d _dispatch_client_callout (in 
libdispatch.dyli  6  0x00007fff85c001fc dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dyli  7  
0x00000001051c4952 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  8  0x00000001051c23ff (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio  9  0x00000001051c2378 (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegratio 10  0x00000001051c2528 (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 11  0x00000001051c4e2e (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 12  0x0000000105162b4f (in \IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 13  0x000000010515bddb (inIDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 14  0x00000001004120ad __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 15  0x0000000100410f22 -
[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 16  
0x0000000100411f03 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 17  0x0000000100412691 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 18  0x0000000100410f22 -
[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 19  
0x0000000100412512 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 20  0x0000000100270b47 -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) 
unarchiveWithDocumentUnarchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 21  0x0000000105162b38 (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 22  0x00000001004120ad __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 23  0x0000000100410f22 -
[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 24  
0x0000000100411f03 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 25  0x0000000105163478 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 26  
0x00000001004120ad __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 27  0x0000000100410f22 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 28  0x0000000100411f03 -
[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 29  
0x0000000100412691 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 30  0x0000000100410f22 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 31  0x0000000100412512 -
[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 32  
0x0000000105217e31 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 33  0x0000000100410f22 -
[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 34  
0x000000010041482c -[IBDocumentUnarchiverGroupMember(unarchiveContentWithBlock) 
unarchiveContentWithBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 35  0x0000000105217d1d (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 36  0x000000010041373c -[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
enumerateGroupMembers:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 37  0x0000000105217c5a (in 
IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 38  0x0000000100410f22 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver 
recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 39  0x000000010041355d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enterGroupWithName:optionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 40  0x0000000105217bd9 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 41  0x000000010027f049 -[IBDocument unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 42  0x0000000105218203 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 43  0x0000000100410f22 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 44  0x00000001004110f6 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 45  0x0000000100279cfb __47-[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 46  0x000000010029cea4 -[IBDocument runBlockInNewArbitrationStackEntryWithBehavior:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 47  0x0000000100279b14 -[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 48  0x0000000105174019 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 49  0x000000010521582c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 50  0x0000000105174094 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 51  0x00007fff8f249098 -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit 52  0x00000001002742d1 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 53  0x0000000100296f9a -[IBDocument invokeWithUndoSuppressed:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 54  0x000000010027408d -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 55  0x0000000100170170 (in ibtoold 56  0x000000010016c50f (in ibtoold 57  0x000000010016b792 (in ibtoold 58  0x000000010016b640 (in ibtoold 59  0x0000000100177f5d (in ibtoold 60  0x000000010016b1a2 (in ibtoold 61  0x000000010016f2ad (in ibtoold 62  0x0000000100169f74 (in ibtooldCommand /Users/easwar/Softwares/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Kindly suggest if you have any idea?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6347731/1378447

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to link against the *System Configuration* framework.

I am mostly guessing and here is my *working out*:

- Googled for `audit_token_to_egid` and [found](http://www.publicsource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-596.12/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkConnection.c) a reference in the source code to `SCNetworkConnection`.
- `SCNetworkConnection` is part of *System Configuration*.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Reference/SCNetworkConnection/Reference/reference.html

Comment: How to do that, could you please explain?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: Actually I am getting this error for all my applications, even for a fresh new application. The fresh new application contain CoreGraphics, Foundation and UIKit frameworks in default. Am I missing something here? What should I add now. Please suggest?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK Ah OK - this looks like system corruption then.  You should reinstall OSX.

Comment: Are you sure? Is the reinstallation only option? Do you have any workarounds?

Comment: As, I had an issue in my XCode 5.1 which is in applications folder, I was getting an error as in my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076866/ios-weird-error-dyld-symbol-not-found-dealloc/24077754#24077754.

To cross check, installed XCode 4.6 in other location but got this issue. Do you think both issues are interconnected?

Really confused...?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK It shouldn't happen and the only thing I can think of is reinstalling the system.

Comment: My heartfelt thanks for your replies.Could you able to check my other question as I said in my previous comment and inter relate?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK Yeah I'd say it was related.

Comment: Ah.. This issue really annoyed me and ate almost 2 days. Thank you so much for your replies.