# Xcode 5.1 iOS simulator 7.1 black screen issue ( dyld: Symbol not found: __dealloc )

Tags: ios, xcode

I cann't start my IOS simulator 7.1 after i update my Xcode into latest version 5.1, and OS X to 10.9.5
When i start the build and run, it shows the build is successful, no issues found. But debug output have this message.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __dealloc
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
(lldb) 

dyld`dyld_fatal_error: 
0x8fe440b4:  int3    
0x8fe440b5:  nop
```

Anyone who know the reason about this issue? i cannt go ahead to do my simulator deployment, and don't know where to go now.

My environment context is as below:

mac-allen:~ allen$ xcodebuild -showsdks

OS X SDKs:

```
OS X 10.8                       -sdk macosx10.8
OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
```

iOS SDKs:

```
iOS 7.1                         -sdk iphoneos7.1
```

iOS Simulator SDKs:

```
Simulator - iOS 6.1             -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
Simulator - iOS 7.1             -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you in fact saying `dealloc` somewhere?

Comment: No, my code didn't have the dealloc in anywhere. Looks this issue is the environment issue. the iOS 7.1 can't work well in Simulator 7.1 or 6.1. Both Simulator have the similar issues. Once i update to iOS8.1, all are ok now.

Answer (score -2):

Issues configuration, looks the iOS 7.1 didn't work well with Simulator 6.1 and 7.1.

mac-allen:~ allen$ xcodebuild -showsdks

OS X SDKs:

```
OS X 10.8                       -sdk macosx10.8
OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
```

iOS SDKs:

```
iOS 7.1                         -sdk iphoneos7.1
```

iOS Simulator SDKs:

```
Simulator - iOS 6.1             -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
Simulator - iOS 7.1             -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
```

After update the iOS 8.1, Simulator 8.1, the Symbol not found issue is gone now.Poor quality tools, cause me tons of time investigating on such issues!

mac-allen:~ allen$ xcodebuild -showsdks

OS X SDKs:

```
OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
OS X 10.10                      -sdk macosx10.10
```

iOS SDKs:

```
iOS 8.1                         -sdk iphoneos8.1
```

iOS Simulator SDKs:

```
Simulator - iOS 8.1             -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
```